# Why the jekyll is not running?

Tags: html, github, jekyll, github-pages, blogs

Hello I have a problem with my blog homepage (https://igorkowalczyk.github.io/blog) does not work, but normal posts such as (https://igorkowalczyk.github.io/blog/categories/offtop) do work.

I don't even know what the problem is.
I suspect that it's a problem with index but I don't know exactly.
Someone knows maybe for what it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`IgorKowalczyk/blog/index.md`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IgorKowalczyk/blog/master/index.md) uses `paginator.posts`, which should be [working only in HTML files](https://github.com/sverrirs/jekyll-paginate-v2/issues/19#issuecomment-290750931), not `md` (markdown files).

The [`categories/offtop.html`](https://github.com/IgorKowalczyk/blog/blob/master/categories/offtop.html) is an *HTML* file, properly rendered/generated by Jekyll.

> - The pagination logic should not sit inside the content files (e.g. individual post or document files). It belongs in the layout files.
> - If you place markdown code into your layout or include files you will have to explicitly pass it through the markdownify filter.
>
> My recommendation is to keep your content (e.g. blog posts) in .md files (which will only contain markdown syntax) and everything dealing with the structure of your site in `.html` files (which will only include HTML syntax).

---

The [OP MAJO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11860129/majo) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504708/why-the-jekyll-is-not-running/59505389#comment105224188_59505389) having to restore the right content for the index.html file: [commit ac2ad43](https://github.com/IgorKowalczyk/blog/commit/ac2ad43c567cc2cf4c3633566d2dd07712e9f803#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3b)

Comment: But in a .html you can only see page structure (same in source of index.md)

Comment: Sorry but your answer not help me :( the .html file have errors...

Comment: Could you write an answer then?

Comment: The solution to this problem sounds crazy. The HTML file itself was faulty (not its content) and it was enough to restore a copy from a few days ago.

Comment: @MAJO OK: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.